# Complex script language view on different phones

Tags: android, unicode

I have problem with complex scripting languages like "Farsi".

As you know before Android 2.3 we have problem with complex script languages. I search a lot and find a class to solve it (it got lots of works).

After some times I got that I have the same problem with both mobile devices and OS versions. For instance with Android 2.3 on two different types of device like Samsung Galaxy Fit and other Samsung device, complex scripting works well and show correct format in one device and on another device doesn't show well.

Is there any option that I do it in correct way in all kinds of devices and OS versions?

Note: In my app I checks SDK version to use or doesn't use complex script language class.